# How to simplify this the most pythonic way?

Tags: python

i have a code like this...

```
if A == 0:
    A = "no"
if B == 0:
    B = "no"
if C == 0:
    C = "no"
if D == 0:
    D = "no"
if E == 0:
    E = "no"
if G == 0:
    G = "no"
```

how to make this simple?

Thank you for answering! Hv a nice day and stay home!

Comment: Use a list to save them can be easy.

Comment: Is there a reason why these are variables and not, say, a ``dict``? Or a ``list``? Is there a reason why they can be either a string or an integer?

Comment: It's time to read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Do you really want to change the variables? It looks to me like these might be yes/no variables, in which case the values are boolean so the variables should be boolean. "no" looks like something you want to display to a user, in which case that should be handled in some display function (If you change the actual data, how would you fix it if users want it displayed in caps, or in Spanish, or whatever?).

Comment: erm i want to display 'no' to the user. actually i want to make a grading system... if the student got 10 As and didnt got any B, it will shows that he got 10As and no B, can u help?

Comment: In that case, first solve _what_ you want to display (the number of As and Bs), and only then _how_ you want to display it (with 'no' instead of 0, ...)

Answer (score 2):

If those variables were in a list or dictionary then you could loop through them.  But since they're just separate variables with no organization, there's not a lot you can do.

You could simplify the code a little by making a function:

```
def zero_to_no(val):
    if val == 0:
        return "no"
    else:
        return val
```

Then your main code would be:

```
A = zero_to_no(A)
B = zero_to_no(B)
# etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it ! Have a nice day and stay safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def convert(a):
    if a == 0:
        return "no"
    return a # or anything you want

a = convert(a)
print(a)

li = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 12, "abcd" ]
print([convert(i) for i in li])
```

Outputs:

```
no
[1, 2, 3, 'no', 'no', 12, 'abcd']
```

Other way to write the same function in Python:

```
def convert(a):
    return 'no' if a == 0 else a# or anything you want
```

However, if they are saved in a list, then using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) makes more sense:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 12, "abcd" ]
print(["no" if x == 0 else x for x in li])
```

Comment: I will try! Thank you and stay safe! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `list`:

```
lst = [A, B, C, D, E, G]

A, B, C, D, E, G = (x or "no" for x in lst)
# A, B, C, D, E, G = ("no" if x == 0 else x for x in lst)
```

Maybe (probably) you don't need all the individual variables at all.

Comment: What if one of them is `False` ?

Comment: Hence the commented variant. Though it better applies to `""`, since `False == 0`. So the OP's code would turn `False` into `"no"` as well.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a dictionary to store your variables so you can change the value of your variables using a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_vars = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'g': 8}
my_vars = {k: 'no' if v == 0 else v for k, v in my_vars.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but this should work for you:

```
def is_not_0(val):
    if val == 0:
        return "no"
    return "yes"

A = is_not_0(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```py
func=lambda *y: ['no' if x==0 else x for x in y]

A, B, C, D, E, G=func(A, B, C, D, E, G)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you make an anonymous function, only to assign it to a name?

Comment: Hm, function is to make it reusable (which I assume is sort of a objective here) and I called it ```func``` cause I didn't want to make assumptions about how it should be called. Not sure, if I understand your point.

Comment: The point of lambda is to define a function *without* a name. A lambda has several restrictions to make this possible. If you directly assign the result of a lambda, you might as well use def, which doesn't have these restrictions.